# AFNetworking 2.0 and authorizing the Imgur API

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, afnetworking, imgur

[Imgur's API](http://api.imgur.com/) requires that for simply looking up information about an image you just need to authorize your app with your API keys, no need to log in with an account or anything.

It says:

> ...all you need to do is send an authorization header with your client_id in your requests

Which apparently looks like:

`Authorization: Client-ID YOUR_CLIENT_ID`

So I tried doing this using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, which appears to be the replacement for `AFHTTPClient` in AFNetworking 2.0 as shown below:

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

```
[operationManager POST:@"https://api.imgur.com/3/image/1Nf1quS" parameters:@{@"Authorization": @"Client-ID ---"} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"failure");
}];
```

Basically tried to send a request with authorization information (I removed my ID for this post). It keeps giving "failure" as a response however.

So I tried playing around with the `credential` property but `NSURLCredential` seems to be based off a username and password, and I have neither of those as I just need my client ID.

So I tried a completely different way again:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.imgur.com/3/image/1Nf1quS"]];
[request addValue:@"Client-ID ---" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[operationManager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"fail");
}];
```

This time using the authorization things as a value on the request. But this one actually never even logged anything.

I'm quite new to API use, so I'm really confused what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

Try this code snippet

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[operationManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Client-ID ---" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[operationManager GET:@"https://api.imgur.com/3/image/1Nf1quS" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"failure");
}];
```

I don't know about Imgur API, but for handling header and stuff, if you are just gonna do a few request to the API, you may add the headers just before the request operation. However, if you need to make API calls in more than one place, I think subclassing AFHTTPRequestOperationManager would be a better way to handle this.

For example you can create a subclass named MRTImgurRequestOperationManager:

```
@interface MRTImgurRequestOperationManager : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager
    + (MRTImgurRequestOperationManager*)sharedManager;
@end
```

and then in your implementation  file:

```
+ (MRTImgurRequestOperationManager*)sharedManager
{
    static MRTImgurRequestOperationManager *_sharedManager;
    static dispatch_once_t _dispatchOnceToken;
    dispatch_once(&_dispatchOnceToken, ^{
        NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"API_URL_HERE"];
        _sharedManager = [[MRTImgurRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    });

    return _sharedManager;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (self)
    {
        // Add headers or other options here
        // For example
        [self.requestSerializer setValue:@"VALUE" forHTTPHeaderField:@"HEADER_NAME"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This way, you can add/remove HTTP headers without ever changing you code in couple of places. This may help with the testing as well.

So to use this, you would:

```
#import "MRTImgurRequestOperationManager.h"
```

and then make your Imgur request with the shared manager.

Edit:

You should use GET, not POST, with the API endpoint you are using

```
[[MRTImgurRequestOperationManager sharedManager] GET:@"path" parameters:params success:success failure:failure]];
```

Comment: Are you sure you are entering authorisation header correctly? I tested with my client ID, and it works fine. Try this: [self.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithToken:@"Client-ID xxxx"] where xxx would be your client id.

Comment: If I put my client id in the other person's block of code, should it work as well? Admittedly I only went off of that, and planned to implement your solution once I had it working.

Comment: Yes, it should work. It is basically doing the same thing. Above code is just more object oriented and clean.

Comment: So this snippet will work for you and return "success" if you literally just change the three --- to *your* client ID? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a890190b6d9985398140 I get failure every time.

Comment: Okay, I may have missed a very important point. You are trying to get an image from that API right? Then you should use GET instead of POST. Try that. Use POST when you are POSTing an image to the API. And instead of setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithToken method do [operationManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Client-ID ---" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"]; . This was my bad, I thought it would do the same thing, apparently it doesn't/

Answer (score 1):

In AFNetworking 2.0 you can set header fields. By using method from `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`

```
- (void)setValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field
```

Try some thing like this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[operationManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Client-ID ---" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[operationManager POST:@"https://api.imgur.com/3/image/1Nf1quS" parameters:@{@"Authorization": @"Client-ID ---"} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"failure");
}];
```

Comment: That gives me this error: `NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: forbidden (403)`